# Prevent LibreOffice from switching language on keyboard layout change

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-layout, libreoffice-writer

When changing the keyboard layout in Windows 7 hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, LibreOffice Writer also changes the language of the text that I enter. No matter what language is set-up for the document, style, or paragraph, it switches to the language that matches the keyboard layout. I haven't found an option to switch this feature off. Do you know where I can find it? And is there any at all?

Comment: There's a [bug report together with a discussion about this issue](https://issues.apache.org/ooo/show_bug.cgi?id=100762), dating from 2009. Since it's confirmed but still open, i fear that there's still no way to disable this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Looks like the developers are rather ignorant of this problem. I assume the solution is to switch to MS Office.

Comment: @Wolfgang seems a bit strong a reaction for one bug. Albeit that it is an annoying one.

Answer (score 3):

This issue has been fixed in Libre Office v4.0. From the Libre Office forum: [Writer: document language changes with keyboard layout - how to remove this behavior?](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/2136/writer-document-language-changes-with-keyboard-layout-how-to-remove-this-behavior/).

There is a new setting to ignore the input language:

[image: Options - Language Settings - Ignore system input Language]

Answer (score -1):

I am experiencing bizarre behavior from Libre Office as well. Besides switching language, the cursor jumps unpredictable, the arrow keys are reversed, it arbitrarily jumps to right-justified, and seemingly unending idiosyncrasies. So switching from this program doesn't seem as such a strong reaction. I'd love to stay with open source, but the bugs are so bad that work is impossible.

Comment: This does not answer the author's question.  Please considering editing your question so it specifically answers the author's question.  Please consider the fact that commentary should never be submitted as an answer.